# Outer Join merge column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, outer-join

My current query involves joining multiple tables and I'm using full outer join for it. However, my query resulted in multiple columns of the same name. How do I combine the result into one single column?

Below is an example of my query

```
 Select table1.a,table1.b AS "chocolate",table2.b AS "chocolate"
 from table1
 full outer join table2 ON table1.c = table2.c
 WHERE table1.a > 100
```

However the column will result in

```
a,chocolate,chocolate
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]
EDIT:  basically I'm just trying to combine inp_pages and art_pages in a single column

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you want to combine these 2 colums ? For example let say that the query gives `dark chocolate` as a value of chocolate column from the left table, and `white chocolate` as a value from the right table. What should be a combined value in this case ?

Comment: @krokodilko They should result in separate rows sharing the same column, wondering if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the attached screenshot, it seems as though only one of the two columns can have a value, and the other is always `null`. If this is true, you could `coalesce` the results into a single column:

```
SELECT          table1.a, COALESCE(table1.b, table2.b) AS "chocolate"
FROM            table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.c = table2.c
WHERE           table1.a > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT function seems to be able to achieve what I want, can anyone help to verify my solution?